# How to resolve a separable differential equation, when one cannot redistribute the variables as desired

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to differential equations, and need to resolve the following:

$k-bv(t)=m \frac{dv(t)}{dt}$

I know this is a separable equation and I know that the correct end-result is:

$v(t)=c_1 e^{-(bt)/m}+\frac{k}{b}$.

While I have the end-result, I am interested in the methodology to get there. My main problem is that, the way I understood separable differential equations, I need to remove the $v$ on the left-hand side of the equation, and get it to the right side, where $dv(t)/dt$ is located, and I am unable to do so.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit $(t)$ for simplicity:
$$k-b.v=m. \frac{dv}{dt} \Longrightarrow \frac{-b}{m}.dt=\frac{-b}{k-b.v}.dv \Longrightarrow \frac{-b}{m}t=\ln(k-b.v)+c_0 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow e^{-bt/m} = (k-bv)e^{c_0} \overset{c_1=-e^{-c_0}}{===\Longrightarrow} v = c_1e^{-bt/m}+\frac{k}{b}$$
Notice that in this case only **Negative** numbers allowed for constant $c_1$.